# My questions suck hard and got me question banned, now what?

Tags: support, post-ban

So yeah, I asked a couple of *really bad questions* on Stack Overflow, and I got downvoted pretty hard. I've been trying to dig myself out for almost a week now, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I have read the sticky, and I did the following:

- Edit my question: I've done this at least 2-3 times for the two questions that got me banned, but honestly they're pretty bad questions, and I can't see any way to salvage them. Besides, every time I edit them, I get neither a mod response nor positive feedback from the community, so it's pointless.
- Answer questions: I try, but I'm not good. I'm just a college student who recently switched into Computer Science. Also, I'm afraid to answer questions because if they're not good, I'll just get downvoted and my ban will extend further.
- Edit existing questions: This essentially is my only venue, but it's a very slow process.
- I have not deleted my questions.

Those two questions I asked at the beginning, I only asked them because I didn't know there were rules against that. I'm not incompetent, I was just ignorant at the time, but **not anymore**. So someone please tell me what I can do, because I don't want to spend weeks editing questions for nothing.

Also, PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE do NOT redirect me to the sticky, because I'm doing everything the sticky is asking me to do already, as evidence by my post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: I read the sticky, but my options truly are limited. Can I really not do anything to dig myself out of this hole besides proofread questions?

Comment: Some of the related questions on the right might help.

Comment: If I edit my questions to be more "substantial", then they will be so different from their original that that will not do any good (unless you're saying I should just go for it anyways).

Comment: Your answers, unfortunately, are pretty borderline as well. [This is the most substantial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21925186/), but I don't personally know if it's right. I think the best advice may be just to use SO in read-only mode for a while, until you have enough experience to post solid answers. (Although [the edits you've been doing](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3050541/zapurdead?tab=activity&sort=revisions) look pretty good; that's appreciated! But unfortunately, I don't think they have any effect on the ban.)

Answer (score 5):

It looks like my question ban has been lifted. Thanks be to the mod who had mercy on me, as well as the upvoters.

Comment: Mods can't lift question bans - but voters can.

Comment: One of my questions that had roughly -7 points disappeared, and I wasn't the one who deleted it.

Comment: No, I deleted it just to get it out of the way; that didn't have any effect on the ban though.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks anyways though lol

Comment: Posting on meta can draw more attention to your posts, if you've made a concerted attempt to improve them (as in this case) that increased attention will lead to upvotes and then the ban is lifted. Keep up the good work

Comment: @Shog9 did you just delete it, or also disassociated it from the OP's account?

Comment: Just deleted, @sha.